# Why does my Mac start up immediately when plugged in, while my iPhone needs to start up?

Tags: iphone, charging

What causes the difference between my mac an my iPhone, where my Mac can boot and become useful immediately after being plugged in, while my phone needs a couple of minutes before it can even start to boot?

It's sometimes a bit frustrating, but in many cases, understanding the reason makes things like this less irritating to me.

Comment: Your Mac is running off the mains whereas your iPhone is running off its battery. The iPhone's battery needs to reach a particular level of charge before it can boot so that it doesn't die during the boot sequence if the charger is disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What causes the difference between my mac an my iPhone, where my Mac
>   can boot and become useful immediately after being plugged in, while
>   my phone needs a couple of minutes before it can even start to boot?

The primary source of power for a mobile device is it’s onboard battery. So it needs to be charged to some degree for the device to work.

When you say your Mac I am going to assume it is a MacBook of some sort. Because in the case of laptops, the system is designed to either run off of the built-in battery power or off of direct AC current if it detects it is plugged into AC power.